# Resolve error "InternalOperationError" when using Azure CLI command to update disableAutomaticRollback setting

Tags: azure-cli

I am attempting to update the property/setting `disableAutomaticRollback` on a virtual machine scale set (VMSS) using this Azure CLI command:

```
az vmss update \
    --resource-group MyResourceGroup123 \
    --name my-vmss-name-here \
    --set upgradePolicy.automaticOSUpgradePolicy.disableAutomaticRollback=true
```

But upon executing the command it runs for around 10 minutes then throws an error "*(InternalOperationError) An internal error occurred in the operation. Code: InternalOperationError Message: An internal error occurred in the operation.*"

I can't understand what the problem is from this vague message. Does the command look correct?

Answer (score 0):

> (InternalOperationError) An internal error occurred in the operation. Code: InternalOperationError Message: An internal error occurred in the operation."

You can follow this [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/error-messages#common-virtual-machine-management-errors) error occurs network profile is not validated properly.

If you are using an old version of the module, a newer version of the tool may fix the problem. Therefore consider updating or upgrading your az module. Also, try running the command in azure cloud shell through the portal.

I tried with the same command in azure cloud shell it worked perfectly.

**Command:**

```
az vmss update --name vmss123 --resource-group "Your-resource-group" --set upgradePolicy.automaticOSUpgradePolicy.disableAutomaticRollback=true
```

**Output:**

```
 "upgradePolicy": {
    "automaticOsUpgradePolicy": {
      "disableAutomaticRollback": true,
      "enableAutomaticOsUpgrade": false,
      "useRollingUpgradePolicy": false
    }
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[az vmss | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vmss-update)

Comment: Thanks Venkatesan. I am actually using the cloud shell in the Azure portal, so I don't think it's possible I've been using an outdated version. I'm not quite understanding the problem, I checked the link you provided but the error message regarding "network profile" was not present in the error message I received. What else could be the cause?

Comment: Refer to this [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-policy?tabs=portal,portal2,portal3,portal4) and [link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-upgrade) of Manage Upgrade Policies for Virtual Machine Scale Sets and try to check the same command with another vmss.